Shopware 6.6 - SearchController - wrong salesChannel handling handleFirstHit
After upgrade from version 6.5.8.9 to 6.6.1.2 I see a strange behaviour in the search.
I have a general salesChannel SC1 (http://localhost:8000) and a second salesChannel SC2 (http://localhost:8000/it-it) in the /it-it salesChannel SC2 I enter a product number and press ENTER. SearchController gets called correctly (http://localhost:8000/it-it/search?search=26179) but in the handleFirstHit method a forwardToRoute is invoked, the salesChannel is then changed to the main one - SC1 - (http://localhost:8000) and the product is not found.
I've seen that forwardToRoute causes a call to RequestTransformer->transform method,in there findSalesChannel gets called but the /it-it is missing from the request path and therefore the wrong domain is found.
Anyone can help me to find out the cause?
UPDATE 1:
Tested on Dockware/play 6.6.1.2 as well to exclude any plugin interference. Created two salesChannels a main one SC1 (domain http://localhost:8000) and a second one SC2 (http://localhost:8000/fr-fr) searching for a product number on the second one causes a forward to the main salesChannel SC1, where the product is not active and therefore not found.
Seems a core bug to me.
